# Set default variables in class

Tags: php, class, object

I got here this code:

```
class Article {
    public $content,$author, $all;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->all = "{$this->author} Wrote: {$this->content}";
    }
}
$newArt = new Article();
$newArt->content = "Lorem ipsum";
```

This is working fine but my question is:
Isn't there any way to set that values automatically in setting new class? Something like:

```
$newArt = new Article("content of content variable", "author");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to set your class members public. Only class methods (functions) should be public, and even then some may be protected and/or private.

By convention, set your class members private or protected, then access them through setters and getters, and have a construct function with your required properties to instantiate your article objects:

```
class Article{
   private $content;
   private $author;
   private $all;

   public function __construct($content, $author){
      $this->content = $content;
      $this->author = $author;
      $this->all = "{$this->author} wrote: {$this->content}";
   }

   public function getAll{
      return $this->all;
   }
}
```

Then, you can call this class in your client script:

```
$article = new Article('Lorem Ipsum', 'William Shakespear');
echo $article->getAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
public function __construct($content, $author) {
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->author = $author;
    $this->all = "{$this->author} Wrote: {$this->content}";
}
```

Other ways depending on the goal, but how does `$this->content` and `$this->author` get set in your existing code?

Comment: beat me to it :) there is some info here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346856/php-constructor-with-parameter

Answer (score 2):

slight modifcation to @AbraCadaver (not enough rep to add comment yet)

```
public function __construct($content='my default content', $author='my default author') {
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->author = $author;
    $this->all = "{$this->author} Wrote: {$this->content}";
}
```

I'm suggesting this because it looks like the OP doesn't require parameters on construction.  This way it can be instantiated without passing anything and if nothing is passed it defaults to some predefined values.

another approach would be:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->content = 'my default content';
    $this->author = 'my default author';
    $this->all = "{$this->author} Wrote: {$this->content}";
}
```

and then use functions like this to set the values later:

```
public set_author ($author) {
   $this->author = $author;
}
```

I prefer keeping variables private and then building set and get public functions myself.  It leaves room for validation and formatting rules to be added later.